# Unable to start journalnode after enabling kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, ambari, hdp

ambari2.7.4 hdp3.1.4

Unable to start journalnode after enabling kerberos

stdout：

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: 
for principal: jn/raw.githubusercontent.com@EAST.COM from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/jn.service.keytab 
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

So strange!  `principal: jn/raw.githubusercontent.com`
Under normal circumstances, my principal should be `jn/myhost`

I don’t know where this URL (raw.githubusercontent.com) comes from?

errout:

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: 
Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ; /usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hadoop/bin/hdfs --config /usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hadoop/conf --daemon start journalnode'' returned 1. 
WARNING: HADOOP_JOURNALNODE_OPTS has been replaced by HDFS_JOURNALNODE_OPTS. Using value of HADOOP_JOURNALNODE_OPTS.
```

Comment: Is EAST.COM your default realm? https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-user/What-is-a-Kerberos-Principal_003f.html

Comment: yes EAST.COM is my default realm.

Comment: Apparently `raw.githubusercontent.com` is what your host name resolves to, or was resolved when you kerberized the cluster. Can you run `$ hostname -A` and check your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: The result of running hostname -A  and cat /etc/hosts  is what I expected，
I can't find this url even if I run `grep -ri raw.githubusercontent.com /`